# boost weak_ptr_cast in shared_from_this()

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using boost's shared pointers, and `enable_shared_from_this` to enable returning a shared pointer to this.  Code looks like this:

```
class foo : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<foo>
{
  boost::shared_ptr<foo> get()
  {
    return shared_from_this();
  }
}
```

Why would shared_from_this throw a weak_ptr_cast exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you declared foo on the stack, so that there are no other shared pointers to foo.  For example:

```
void bar()
{
  foo fooby;
  fooby.get();
}
```

fooby.get() would throw the `weak_ptr_cast` exception.

To get around this, declare `fooby` on the heap:

```
void bar()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<foo> pFooby = boost::shared_ptr<foo>(new foo());
  pFooby->get();
}
```

Another possibility is that you're trying to use `shared_from_this` before the constructor is done, which would again try to return a shared pointer that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Calling `shared_from_this()` from the constructor is probably *the* reason for `shared_from_this()` to fail (I mean while developing, not in production code of course). Unfortunately the best (only?) solution seems to be to use two-phase construction (with all it's drawbacks).