# Boost shared_from_this() returning wrong shared_ptr

Tags: boost, shared-ptr

I'm trying to use `boost::shared_ptr` and `boost::enable_shared_from_this` to no avail. It looks as if `shared_from_this()` is returning the wrong `shared_ptr`. Here is what I see:

```
Task* task = new TaskSubClass();
boost::shared_ptr<Task> first = boost::shared_ptr<Task>(task); // use_count = 1, weak_count = 1
boost::shared_ptr<Task> second = first; // use_count = 2, weak_count = 1
boost::shared_ptr<Task> third = first->shared_from_this(); // use_count = 2, weak_count = 2
```

I also noticed that `first.px = third.px` but `first.pn.pi != third.pn.pi`. That is, they both share the same object but they use a different counter. How can I get the two to share the same counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was caused by the fact that TaskSubClass's constructor invoked some method that, in turn, invoked `new boost::shared_ptr<Task>(this)` instead of `new boost::shared_ptr<Task>(shared_from_this())`. As an added bonus, [you're not supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459414/boost-weak-ptr-cast-in-shared-from-this/459421#459421) invoke `shared_from_this()` from the constructor and the documentation is far from obvious on this point: `There must exist at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns t.` It makes sense in retrospect, but the documentation should really be more explicit :)

Sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: What could an owner of a non-created-object-yet look like?

Comment: @curiousguy I'm not sure. This question is almost 9 years old and I don't remember the details :)